# Does passing parameters in lambda's capture to boost asio post/dispatch thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, synchronization, boost-asio

I'm using `lambda's capture` in order to pass parameters to `boost::asio::io_context::post` callback.
Is it thread safe?

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include <thread>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work work(io_service);

    std::thread t([&](){
        io_service.run();
    });

    auto var = 1;
    io_service.post([&io_service, var]() {
        std::cout << "v: " << var << std::endl;
        io_service.stop();
    });

    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I pass `var` in the `lambda's capture`.
the `main thread` sets `var`'s value, and thread `t` reads it.
I didn't use any of `memory ordering`, for example, `std::memory_order_release` after setting `var` to `1`, and `std::memory_order_acquire` before reading `var` value. Even more, I don't think I can - because the variable `var` is passed by value to the `lambda`.

Is it safe to do that?
If not, how should it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is thread-safe.

Closure object is created by main thread (with copying `var` value) after `var` was created and initialized.
Next, closure object is passed as argument to `post` method which queues this function object and returns immediately without calling functor. Functor is called between `post` and `t.join` calls - `post` guarantees it.
So your code must be thread-safe.

You would need some synchronization method (for example, use of `mutex`+`lock_guard`) 
if `var` was passed by reference [1] and some writing operations on `var` [2]
were performed between `post` and `t.join` calls:

```
auto var = 1;
io_service.post([&io_service, &var]() { // [1] takes by reference
    std::cout << "v: " << var << std::endl; // lock mutex for printing
    io_service.stop();
});
var = 10; // [2] , lock mutex for writing
// synchronization must be added because between post and t.join calls,
// reading and writing operations are executed
t.join();
```

in this case you would have to protect `var`.

Comment: So, are you saying: as the `lambda` passes into thread `t` and get queued and executed successfully, the variable also passes?

Comment: If `var` is passed by value to lambda, closure object holds it as data member (copy of this `var`), so while passing closure to thread , we can say that the copy of `var` is passed.